# How can i trap invocation of methods in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to trap invocation of a method and then display output.

```
class A 

end
```

If i run new A.see it should trap and print 'unkown method'.

I am new to the language

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am new to the language learning i am surprised by kind of people on this website not very helpful but bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a message to an object, the object executes the first method it finds on its method lookup path with the same name as the message. If it fails to find any such method, it raises a NoMethodError exception, unless you have provided the object with a method called `method_missing`. The `method_missing` method is passed the symbol of the non-existent method, an array of the arguments that were passed in the original call and any block passed to the original method.

```
class A 
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
    puts "There's no method called #{m} here -- please try again."  
    super
  end  
end
```

Comment: As a rule-of-thumb I would add `super` to the end of any `method_missing` implementation when the call is not actually handled.

Answer (score 0):

This already triggers a NoMethodError that by default halts your program.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `see' for A:Class
```

Comment: hello mister that is after person edit to include URI AGASI comment.. If i dont want that error i call without super ..what do you ask?